# some conceptual part for express js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

If I use  `const homeModel = require('../models/home')` in the `router.post` call then `homeModel` gives me the whole `homeModel` object. However when I use `const homeModel = require('../models/home')` in global, then
`homeModel` produces an empty object (`{}`).

Why is this happening?

**Routes/Comment.js**

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const userModel = require('../models/user');
const commentModel = require('../models/comment');

//importing middleware
const {
  AuthMiddleWare
} = require('../middleware/middleware');

router.post('/comment/:id', AuthMiddleWare, (req, res) => {
      // important
      const homeModel = require('../models/home'); //         <--talking about this 

      const postId = req.params.id;
      // console.log(postId);
      const {
        comment
      } = req.body;
      console.log(homeModel);
      console.log(userModel);
      console.log(commentModel);

      homeModel.findById(postId, (err, post) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              //finding Current  user
              userModel.findOne({
                  email: req.session.passport.user
                }, (err, user) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    //founded Current user

                    // post

                    // create}
                  })
              })
```

**Models/home.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { post } = require('../routes/auth');
const user = require('./user');

let homePageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    image: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user'
        },
        name: String
    },

    postDescription: String,
    like: [ String ],
    disLike: [ String ],
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'comment'
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Home', homePageSchema);
```

Routes and path is here Photo is here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK8Yc.png)

Comment: `const homeModel = require('../models/home');` will get the default export which is likely empty. Depends on what is exported in `'../models/home'`

Comment: add your home model must be some problem with your export

Comment: It will be helpful for us to identify the issue if you share the `../models/home`

Comment: i updated my posts..... i think my module export right because when i `const homeModel = require('../models/home');` gobally then it's give a **{} / empty object** bur when it's  define `const homeModel = require('../models/home');` in `router.post('/comment/:id',` it's give me  **whole homeModule Object**